# Irregular layout ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, layout, itemscontrol

I have a strange layout for an ItemsControl.

I have a 4x6 grid with the following pattern:

```
1  2  3  4 
13 14 15 16
5  6  7  8
17 18 19 20
9  10 11 12
21 22 23 24
```

Is there an easy way to do this? should I be using 6 Items Controls and take "sections" of my list?  is there a good way to do this? What about notification?

It's important to note that I may, or may not, have all 24 entries present, but the layout needs to be maintained (think of it like filled slots on a bingo card or something)

Edit:

Ideally, I'd like to be able to take a list, and do some fun sorting/padding type stuff off properties on the items in the list.

for instance, if I have an ObservableCollection with a few units, and Unit has a property "Index", I'd like to have a view consumable Collection generated that automatically uses Index to make a padded list.  I guess an observable dictionary could work, but that seems gross.  Maybe a new custom layout panel is in order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a clever way of doing this in pure XAML using a custom template for your ItemsControl.  It's easiest if all your "cards" have a fixed size, say 100x100:

```
<!-- Wrap each card in a decorator twice as high as the card cell -->
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemInDoubleHighBox">
  <Decorator Width="100" Height="200">
    <Decorator Width="100" Height="100" ClipToBounds="True">
      <ContentPresenter />
    </Decorator>
  </Decorator>
</DataTemplate>

<!-- Define a template for use with WrapPanel -->
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="WrapPanelTemplate">
  <WrapPanel />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>

<!-- Now the actual ItemsControl template -->
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
  <Grid Width="600" Height="600" ClipToBounds="True">

    <!-- Items 1 to 12 -->
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}"
                  ItemsPanel="{StaticResource WrapPanelTemplate}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemInDoubleHighBox}" />

    <!-- Items 13 to 24 -->
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}"
                  ItemsPanel="{StaticResource WrapPanelTemplate}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemInDoubleHighBox}"
                  RenderTransform="1 0 0 1 0 -500" />

  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

How it works:  The DataTemplate causes the items to be "double-spaced" with only 1-12 visible, and the RenderTransform on the second ItemsControl makes items 13-24, which are also "double-spaced" appear in the spaces between the first rows of items.

Note:  You can make the height and width data-bindable, but it takes more XAML.  Just add ScaleTransforms everywhere "200", "500" or "600" appears in the XAML.  For example, to deal with the "200" you can set a scale transform on the inner decorator with ScaleY="0.5" and on each ItemsControl with ScaleY="2".  Now the outer decorator's height will be 100, which can be data-bound.  The other constants can be dealt with via similar pre- and post- scaling of the content.  And because WPF combines all the transforms before rendering anyway, the extra transforms will cost basically nothing.

Comment: why the use of decorators? also I'm confused as to how this "Splits" my items into 1-12 & 13-24

Otherwise, I like this answer.

Answer (score 0):

WPF makes this pretty trivial. Basically you just need to specify an ItemsPanelTemplate.

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="4" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Now whatever items you add to the ListBox will be arranged according to the layout logic of the panel which in this case is a UniformGrid.

Note that you'll still need to keep the items in your collection in the order that you want them to appear. So I would sort them out first before adding them to the ListBox. If you need to create "holes" in the collection then I would use some type of placeholder object (maybe new object() will do) instead of trying to use complex layout logic to spread the items.

Comment: aren't there collection adapter classes specifically for WPF?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There's really two parts to this question. The layout aspects (making items in a ListBox show up in a grid) is simple. But I don't fully understand how you intend on getting the items into the collection in the first place.